# graphics.setColor(color); not working

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, awt, rgb

I'm trying to create a little tower defense game **with colors** but the colors aren't working here's how I draw rects do graphics.

```
public static void fill(GridLocation loc, Color c){
    Main.frame.getGraphics().setColor(c);
    Main.frame.getGraphics().fillRect(loc.toFrameLocation().x, loc.toFrameLocation().y, 20, 20);
    Main.frame.getGraphics().dispose();
}
```

and and this is how I call/create the JFrame

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("Tower defense");
    frame.setSize(1000, 700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    while (frame.isVisible()){
        Grid.fill(new GridLocation(1,1), new Color(1F,0F,0F));
        Grid.fill(new GridLocation(2,1), Color.gray);
        Grid.drawGrid();
        Grid.fill(new GridLocation(3,1), Color.green);
    }
}
```

My problem: the rectangles are always black?

Comment: This is not the way to achieve this. Read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: 1. Draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel. 2. Use a Swing Timer not a `while (true)` loop. 3. Within that Timer, change the state of the drawing JPanel (change its fields), and then call repaint(). 4. Then have the paintComponent method use the fields to tell it how to draw. 5. Don't forget to call the super's painting method within your override.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter, user1803551 Thanks it works now!

Comment: Glad that it's working. Your problem was that you were making wild guesses on how to do Swing graphics and animations, and that won't work with a complex subject like this. The tutorials won't steer you wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if you use `getGraphics()` on a component to get your Graphics context, the graphics thus obtained will not persist. For example in the code below, you'll see that if the button is pressed, a blue rectangle appears, but it then disappears if the GUI is minimized and later resized.

Also, as per my comments:

1. Draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel.
2. Use a Swing Timer not a while (true) loop.
3. Within that Timer, change the state of the drawing JPanel (change its fields), and then call repaint().
4. Then have the paintComponent method use the fields to tell it how to draw.
5. Don't forget to call the super's painting method within your override.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UnstableStableGraphics extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 400;
    private static final int GAP = 20;

    public UnstableStableGraphics() {
        add(new JButton(new DrawBlueRectAction()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        int w = PREF_W / 2 - 2 * GAP;
        int h = PREF_H - 2 * GAP;
        g.fillRect(GAP, GAP, w, h);     
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class DrawBlueRectAction extends AbstractAction {
        public DrawBlueRectAction() {
            super("Draw Unstable Blue Rectangle");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            int x = PREF_W / 2 + GAP;
            int w = PREF_W / 2 - 2 * GAP;
            int h = PREF_H - 2 * GAP;
            g.fillRect(x, GAP, w, h);
            g.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        UnstableStableGraphics mainPanel = new UnstableStableGraphics();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("UnstableStableGraphics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Having said that, it is perfectly fine to use a Graphics object obtained via `getGraphics()` called on a BufferedImage (as long as you dispose of the Graphics object when done, to conserve resources when done), and then display that image in the paintComponent method, often as a background image. Usually, however, I call `createGraphics()` on the BufferedImage since that returns the more powerful Graphics2D object, and not a Graphics object.

For example, including use of a background image, a sprite image and a Swing Timer:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BackgroundExample extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final int SPRITE_W = 20;
    private static final Color SPRITE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
    private Image background = null;
    private Image sprite = null;
    private int spriteX = 0;
    private int spriteY = 0;

    public BackgroundExample() {
        background = createBackground();
        sprite = createSprite();

        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
    }

    private Image createSprite() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(SPRITE_W, SPRITE_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(SPRITE_COLOR);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        int width = SPRITE_W -2;
        int height = SPRITE_W - 2;
        g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        g2.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    private Image createBackground() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        g2.fillRect(x, y, 2 * SPRITE_W, 2 * SPRITE_W);
        x = PREF_W - 2 * SPRITE_W;
        g2.fillRect(x, y, 2 * SPRITE_W, 2 * SPRITE_W);
        y = PREF_H - 2 * SPRITE_W;
        g2.fillRect(x, y, 2 * SPRITE_W, 2 * SPRITE_W);
        x = 0;
        g2.fillRect(x, y, 2 * SPRITE_W, 2 * SPRITE_W);
        g2.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (background != null) {
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        }
        if (sprite != null) {
            g.drawImage(sprite, spriteX, spriteY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H); 
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            spriteX++;
            spriteY++;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BackgroundExample mainPanel = new BackgroundExample();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BackgroundExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because you take much energy into this answer.